# how can i start wso2 dss service automatically

Tags: web-services, wso2

I have a wso2 dss with one service. I need that service be active when i run the server. So if my server run automatically when start Operative System, it´s mandatory that my service be active too, but this not happen.
Until now i most go to the management console and activate it manually.
Once active, works fine, without problems.
I hope you can help me.

My service it's a simple dataservice service. Yes, that's happening @gusto2. I let you the log wso2carbon.log when try to deploy the service.

```
{org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-07 10:03:58,526] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer} -  The Servicio_SICA.dbs service, which is not valid, caused {1} {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-07 10:03:59,159] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ServiceAdmin} -  Invalid service name, service not found : Servicio_SICA {org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ServiceAdmin}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-07 10:03:59,175] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.ServiceAdminClient} -  Cannot get service data. Backend service may be unavailable {org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.ServiceAdminClient}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid service name, service not found : Servicio_SICA
```

Comment: Are you running on Windows or linux? In either case you can use schdule task (Windows scheduler or linux service) to start the DSS server as a service

Comment: The question is about a service in DSS I think.

Comment: Yes, my question is about the service in dss. The server works fine, but i need a service running automatically when the server start. Today the service only is activated manually from management console.

Comment: Usually, you don't have to do that. Everything gets deployed when the server is started. What you observe is strange. What's your DSS version and OS?

Comment: If it is a Linux box, you can write an init/systemd scripts in order to start it. On windows, you have to start it as a service. That means using something like yajsw (http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/), commons-daemon (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/) or Tanuki Software´s JSW (https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com). WSO2´s docs also have some info: https://docs.wso2.com/x/4Ru2AQ

Comment: @AdrianRamírez  you mean - you start the DSS and the defined service is not active by default? What type of the service it is? (simple dataservice dbs definition?) any warning / exceptino in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you start wso2 service your database or some wsdl services not start yet? Wso2 has a problem with it, because can create pooling on startup or something else. You can add dependency to your wso2dss service to your database, if you start it as service.